# Apache Camel jackson unmarshaller dont work

Tags: java, jackson, apache-camel, camel-jackson

Im using camel and jackson for unmarshalling string with json

```
{"GUID":"123"}


... .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, TestPojo.class)
```

And hava pojo

```
    TestPojo {
     @JsonProperty("GUID)
     private String guid;

     @JsonProperty("GUID")
     public String getGuid(){
      return guid;
     }
     @JsonProperty("GUID")
     public String setGuid(){
      return guid;
     }
    }
```

But have this exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "GUID" (class package.TestPojo), not marked as ignorable (1 known properties: "guid")
```

Im tested route with processor, which work fine

```
        .process(e -> {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            e.getIn().setBody(mapper.readValue(e.getIn().getBody(String.class),TestPojo.class));
        })
```

What im doing wrong?

Comment: it is enough to have the @JsonProperty annotation on the field. It is not required on the getter/setter. Try using @JsonProperty(value = "GUID")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your setguid is returning the guid in lowercase. However, in the json body, the guid is capitalized (GUID). Try to capitalize the guid or set.

```
public void setGUID(String GUID){
  this.GUID = GUID
```

}